# Choose one in two rdf:type sparql

Tags: rdf, sparql

I have content of rdf file like this :

```
 <owl:Thing rdf:about="http://hust.se.vtio.owl#hanoi-big-church">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://hust.se.vtio.owl#Church"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;NamedIndividual"/>
```

I want use sparql query to response result `http://hust.se.vtio.owl#hanoi-big-church` and i queried

```
?uri rdf:type ?type
```

but is responsed `&owl;NamedIndividual`
How should i do? Thank for helping!

Comment: That's a valid response, since `<rdf:type rdf:resource="&owl;NamedIndividual"/>`.  What was your query?  Did you get any other results that you didn't want?  It's not too hard to filter out this specific one, but in general, things can have lots of `rdf:type`s.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor : I want result :`http://hust.se.vtio.owl#hanoi-big-church`

Comment: Please include your query in the question, though, since most ways of querying would provide multiple responses.  It's not clear whether you got _multiple_ results, and you only want one, or whether (somehow) you only got one result and didn't get the other at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evidently you've got data that is more or less like this (in the future, it will be very helpful if you can provide complete, but minimal, working examples):

```xml
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:owl="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#"
    xmlns="http://hust.se.vtio.owl#" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://hust.se.vtio.owl#hanoi-big-church">
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://hust.se.vtio.owl#Church"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual"/>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing"/>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

As you noted, a query like the following will produce multiple results:

```
prefix : <http://hust.se.vtio.owl#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?type where {
  :hanoi-big-church a ?type
}
```

```
-----------------------
| type                |
=======================
| owl:Thing           |
| owl:NamedIndividual |
| :Church             |
-----------------------
```

You can filter out results that are IRIs beginning with the `owl:` namespace, though by converting `?type` to a string with [str](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-str) and checking with [strstarts](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-strstarts).

```
prefix : <http://hust.se.vtio.owl#>
prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>

select ?type where {
  :hanoi-big-church a ?type .
  filter(!strstarts(str(?type),str(owl:)))
}
```

```
-----------
| type    |
===========
| :Church |
-----------
```

Now, in this particular case, you're getting a single result because you've filtered out two of three values.  It's important to note, though, that things can have many types, so if your data had also said that `:hanoi-big-church` was a `:Building`, you'd get two results (`:Church` and `:Building`).